# RSS reader with windows notifications

Tags: windows-7, rss, notifications

I am looking for an RSS reader that I can run minimized in my notifications task bar and that will post a notification whenever there is an update to one of the feeds.

Comment: I just use Google Reader with either browser or Rainmeter plugins for this, but probably not exactly what you're after...

Comment: Yeah, I'm specifically looking for integration with windows notifications.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[rssowl](http://www.rssowl.org)

> The Notifier is a small popup that displays the headlines of incoming news even when RSSOwl is minimized. You can mark news entries as sticky from the Notifier to remember reading the full content of the entry at a later time.

Comment: Perfect!  It does everything I needed and then some.

Comment: From it's Github page: «RSSOwl is unmaintained and has several known vulnerabilities. Please do not use it any more.» https://github.com/rssowl/RSSOwl
There are active forks, though.

Answer (score 4):

[Feed Notifier](http://www.feednotifier.com/)

> Feed Notifier is a Windows application
>   that resides in the system tray and
>   displays pop-up notifications on your
>   desktop when new items arrive in your
>   subscribed RSS or Atom feeds. By
>   default, the pop-ups look like this…

[image]

Comment: rssowl is a resource hog.  I'll have to take a look at this.  Thanks (+1).

Comment: FWIW, I developed Feed Notifier. Let me know if you have any feedback.